# How can I print the translated entity title in a template?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a reference field for nodes and I have a field template to render the the fields.

```
{{ item.entity.title.value }}
```

But I can't get the translated title of the node.

Can someone help?

Comment: Normally the title should be switched automatically depending on the currently selected interface language. Where and how do you want to use it? Was the node already translated or how else was the title translated?

Comment: The node was translated. And thats what I thought. That Drupal is smart enough ;) ... to get the translation.

Comment: I use it in an Node as a reference. To follow the layout we had to use a field template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure the reference field to display the entity title it should be translated automatically, as @leymannx commented. But if you get the title from the entity directly you have to make sure the entity is in the correct language. If you don't want to use PHP you can do this with the help of [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
{{ item.entity|translation.title.value }}
```

See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#entity-translation

Comment: I tried `{{ item.entity.translation(lang).title.value }}` and `{{ item.entity|translation.title.value }}` and other combinations. But always get an WSOD page with an error message.

We use twig tweak and for all other things we use it works perfect, but thats the only problem we got stuck with.

Comment: The second version with a pipe symbol for the Twig filter seems to be correct if you iterate field items `{% for item in element['#items'] %}`. Do you have the latest version of Twig Tweak? `|translation` was added quite recently.

Comment: I have Version Version: 8.x-2.9.

Comment: OK now it works!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH for this simple solution to update!!!!!!!